# what mean .length property in an array variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

Can I ask what mean .length property in the array variable? I look through many article and many of them stated that .length return the number of string. So can anyone give me an answer?
Below is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var mycars = new Array();
mycars[0] = "Saab";
mycars[1] = "Volvo";
mycars[2] = "BMW";

for (i=0;i<mycars.length;i++)
{
document.write(mycars[i] + "<br />");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) returns the number of elements in the array. That's how many items you need to iterate over in your `for` loop when looking at all of them.

Comment: Oh so you are there now +1 ;-)

Comment: @Sarfraz - Was out getting furniture for the new place all of yesterday ;)

Comment: Well congratz and happy new year :)

Comment: Thanks, answer will be accepted in 5 minuites. Happy New Year!!